# Amazon RDS Instance Password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'll preface this with the statement that I hate using these Amazon servers.

Ok what I need to know is how to find the password for a specific Amazon RDS instance.  I have a live instance running my store and working on setting up a development copy.  So I lauched a copy of the DB but can't seem to find the password for this new DB instance anywhere.

I created a Snapshot, then restored from the snapshot just with a new instance identifier.  So would the passwords be the same on both instances?

Thanks!

Comment: Answer: There is a "Set Master Password" field that can be set on instance creation.  If copied it will have the same password, or you can set a new one here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they should have the same password.