# How to connect DBeaver to cloned Amazon Aurora DB?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, dbeaver

I have an Aurora PostgreSQL database on RDS:

[image]

I can successfully connect to it via DBeaver.

[image]

However, if I create another DB via clicking on *Actions -> Create clone*:

[image]

and create a DB, I cannot connect to that. In the form which comes up after I click *Create clone*, I did not change the default values. I named my DB, specified an ACU count and provided an *Initial database name* (as the form tells me: *If you do not specify a database name, Amazon RDS does not create a database.*, see below).

[image]

Whenever I try to connect, I get:

[image]

I believe the master password should be the same (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170960/amazon-rds-instance-password) for example).

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cloning doesn't mean all settings are copied, only some. If I set *Public Access* to *Yes* on the cloning form:

[image]

then the connection issue is resolved.